# Getting 'java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' with grails run-app (when BuildConfig.groovy doesn't need to be recompiled)

Tags: mysql, grails, jetty

I've upgraded my grails application from 1.3.9 to 2.2.3 and then to 2.3.3. I read the release and upgrade notes for 1.3.9->2.2.3 and then from 2.2.3->2.3.3

I am using `OpenJDK 6`, `Jetty 6` and the plugin `jetty 1.1`, `MySQL 5.5` and I have the connector library under `lib`

Now my issue is if I run `grails clean` and then `grails run-app` the application runs without any problems but if I stop it and run `grails run-app` again I get a gigantic error (see here: http://pastebin.com/36MpXhir)

I also found that changing something like adding a space somewhere in `BuildConfig.groovy` (anything that makes it be recompiled) makes the application run normally.

Looking at the stacktrace the first thing that puzzles me is

```
    [02.12.13 16:13:59.919] [main] pool.ConnectionPool Unable to create initial connections of pool.
    java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.afterPropertiesSet(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:162)
```

There are references to `org.apache.tomcat` even though I'm using jetty (and removed tomcat from `BuildConfig.groovy`).

Did anyone else encounter such a problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't put jar files in the lib directory if they're available in a public Maven repo. It's far better to download jars once and keep them in a local cache, and reuse them as needed.

The MySQL driver is used as the commented-out example in the generated `BuildConfig.groovy` - just un-comment it :)  You might want to bump up the version to the latest, e.g.

```
dependencies {
   runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
}
```

This is a good site for finding Maven artifacts: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

If you do have a jar that's not in a Maven repo (e.g. one with shared code at your company) then you can put it in the lib directory, but it's not auto-discovered. Run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` to get it added to the classpath.

Comment: Apparently it cannot resolve the plugin:

| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27

Comment: It's a jar, not a plugin :)  Make sure that `mavenCentral()` is uncommented and listed in the `repositories` block, and it's a good idea to include `mavenLocal()` also (and before `mavenCentral()`) so it checks your local cache first. If that doesn't work, do what the error message suggests - change the log level to warn (`log 'warn'`) and see if the extended output has any more hints.

Comment: Hey, just tried it out this morning and it looks like it's working. Thank you very much! :D

I am still a little puzzled as to why it worked when it had to recompile BuildConfig.groovy though.

Answer (score -1):

```
For me same error has occurred while running the Grails Application.Then I debug and view the code history of my code which was committed recently.
From that I found the issue that was:
 Inside the controller file I send the instance with-out properly
 Eg:
    **def list=[personInstance.]---> error occurred.**
    **render list as JSON**
 Then I correct my mistake-->clean the app --> run the app
 Now its working fine.
```